# How to set an Azure SSO/MFA in front of a app with basic authentication?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, multi-factor-authentication

Currently I have problem with an app, especially  with the required authentications standards in our company.
We need ad authentication for all our apps we use in the company.
A new software from a special department provides basic authentication only.
So my plan is to set a small authenication app in front of these app. When the user is authenticated the application redirects the user to the login mask of the actual app.
Before I start here with the development of a stupid idea, I want to ask you if there are better solutions or prectises out there to handle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Azure With modern authentication and security features in Azure AD, that basic password should be supplemented or replaced with more secure authentication methods. The application should support modern authentication in order to have a additional security like MFA.

Kindly check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-authentication-methods) in order to get a detailed information about the authentication and verification method in Azure. Here as per your statement you were trying to setup a small app in front of the application and if it's can be done its great. But since application support only basic authentication there is no known solution from Azure end.